# Creating Triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger for the first time. I would like to update multiple fields in table (Opps) once another field, within the same table, is amended. I am not sure that Triggers are the best way to go about it, but I think it is. The fields I want to update are (currStage) and (stageDate) with the second field being the date that the original field (Stage) was amended. Does that make sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am lost right now.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...?

Comment: Usually, if you're wanting to understand changes to a table, it's better to log to a second table - or are you saying that you'll *only ever* care about the most recent change to the table (E.g. Ignoring a different change that happened 5 minutes before)

Comment: So basically it is a custom Outlook form that talks to SQL db. So I have created form code so that it behaves the way I want it if the form is open. If they use a bulk updater tool though, it forces data without using the code. So I want to use SQL triggers to force the changes through. I only care about the one table, but all updates made. Does that answer your question?

Comment: SQL is _not_ a database though. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server etc are databases. As each has it's own procedural language you'll _have_ to specify which RDBMS you're using to get relevant help. Generally, it's always better to do this as each RDBMS has some additional functions etc that could be helpful.

Comment: It's possible that your "bulk updater tool" may [bypass triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640.aspx) as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it is a SQL Server database Ben. And Tim, I am aware that it may do that also, obvioulsy thorough testing will take place.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach will be to use API, create stored procedure for UPDATE,INSERT, and DELETE. And update use your UPDATE procedure to update other tables. It's no a good practice to overuse triggers. For comparison between API and trigger approach please check [this](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/oracle-guide/when-to-use-triggers-and-when-not-to-24837)

Comment: I am not in a position to use an API, unfortunately, triggers are the only way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

People sometimes have unique business needs, and it sounds like you are in one of those situations.
You can use an AFTER INSERT trigger to update fields with new values.
When the trigger fires you can do an UPDATE/SET/WHERE

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_stages_MyTable
ON MyTable
AFTER INSERT 
BEGIN
   UPDATE MyTable
   SET currStage = 'whatever value I want', stageDate = getdate()
   WHERE Stage = 'the stage Ijust updated'
END;
```

Let me know if this makes sense and meets your business needs.